# Converting "9954-4740-4491-4414" to "99:54:47:40:44:91:44:14" using Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex

If the title isn't clear enough, here's a procedural way of approaching the problem:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Foo()
{
    var start = "9954-4740-4491-4414";

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < start.Length; i++)
    {
        if ( start[i] != '-')
        {
            if (j == 2)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat(":{0}", start[i]);
                j = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(start[i]);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    var end = sb.ToString();

    Assert.AreEqual(end, "99:54:47:40:44:91:44:14");
}
```

Comment: I'd start by changing the regex to `(\d{2})(\d{2})` and then try to extract the capture groups. If I had a C# compiler/runtime over here, I'd try to write some actual code. On the other hand, why bother with regular expressions? Why not just remove all of the `-` characters and then build your output string by moving through the string of digits? Regex wouldn't be necessary there.

Comment: This is for the sake of curiosity, not functionality or necessity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using C# 4 all you need is this:

```
string result = string.Join(":", Regex.Matches(start, @"\d{2}").Cast<Match>());
```

For C# 3 you need to provide a `string[]` to Join:

```
string[] digitPairs = Regex.Matches(start, @"\d{2}")
                           .Cast<Match>()
                           .Select(m => m.Value)
                           .ToArray();
string result = string.Join(":", digitPairs);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a perfect answer.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with "why bother with regular expressions?"

```
string.Join(":", str.Split('-').Select(s => s.Insert(2, ":"));
```

Comment: I like your code as well! I asked this question just to see what others would come up with. I love pretty code and my initial run through was ugly to me. Yours though... so choice.

Comment: Had to change it to string.Join(":",start.Split('-').Select(s => s.Insert(2, ":")).ToArray()); to compile in 3.5

Comment: @Merritt Only needed if you want to save it to an array, of course.

Comment: string.Join only excepts string arrays in 3.5

Comment: Then call .ToArray() after the .Select

Answer (score 2):

Regex.Replace version, although I like Mark's answer better:

```
string res = Regex.Replace(start, 
   @"(\d{2})(\d{2})-(\d{2})(\d{2})-(\d{2})(\d{2})-(\d{2})(\d{2})", 
   @"$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6:$7:$8");
```

Answer (score 1):

After a while of experimenting, I've found a way to do it by using a single regular expression that works with input of unlimited length:

```
Regex.Replace(start, @"(?'group'\d\d)-|(?'group'\d\d)(?!$)", @"$1:")
```

When using named groups (the `(?'name')` stuff) with same name, captures are stored in the same group. That way, it is possible to replace distinct matches with same value.

It also makes use of [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (the `(?!)` stuff).

Comment: You definitely kicked it up a notch. I've got to say it's almost grotesque in its beauty. I love it... love it.

Comment: How about this? `Regex.Replace(start, @"(\d{2})-?(?!$)", "$1:")`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need them: strip the '-' characters and then insert a colon between each pair of numbers. Unless I've misunderstood the desired output format.